# Contrasting results between bulk file rename utility and windows script

Tags: windows, powershell, filepath, file-rename, windows-scripting

So I was using this command `cmd /c dir /s /b |? {$_.length -gt 260}` to find out a list of paths that exceed **Windows** limit of 260 characters. And this gave me 4 `files` when pointed to a folder. Then I used "Bulk File Rename" utility from this link http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Download.php on the same folder keeping the path length as 260 and that gave me 6 files.

On checking those 2 files which were not pulled by the command but by the utility I found out that they are actually more than 260 characters and cannot be opened.

My question is any reason why this command `cmd /c dir /s /b |? {$_.length -gt 260}` is not 100% accurate?

Comment: **1**. Try `cmd /c dir /s /b /a |? {$_.length -gt 260}`. **2**. Please [edit] your question and **2a**. add link to _"Bulk File Rename" utility_ (is it a command line tool or a GUI tool?) and **2b**.  add `PowerShell` tag (I guess that `|? {$_.length -gt 260}` is a `PowerShell` construct?)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I have done them

Comment: I tried your solution indicated in step 1. But the result set stays the same as before.

Comment: could you add those 6 filenames to your post and tell us which was found by which tool?